# PHP - How to assign string key and value for array within 2 foreach loops?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, variable-assignment

The problem I have is that value gets overwritten in second foreach loop. I need to set the key to image thumbnail link and set value to an image path.

```
$img_thumbs = array('folder/thumb1.jpg','folder/thumb2.jpg','folder/thumb3.jpg');
$img_links = array('folder/image1.jpg','folder/image2.jpg','folder/image3.jpg');

$imgs = array();

foreach($img_links as $img_val)
{       
    foreach($img_thumbs as $thum_val)
    {
        $imgs[$thum_val] = $img_val
    }
}   

print_r($imgs);
```

**OUTPUT** (notice how image value repeats the last value):

```
Array ( 
      ["folder/thumb1.jpg"] => ["folder/image3.jpg"],
      ["folder/thumb2.jpg"] => ["folder/image3.jpg"],
      ["folder/thumb3.jpg"] => ["folder/image3.jpg"]
)
```

**WHAT I NEED**:

```
Array ( 
      ["folder/thumb1.jpg"] => ["folder/image1.jpg"],
      ["folder/thumb2.jpg"] => ["folder/image2.jpg"],
      ["folder/thumb3.jpg"] => ["folder/image3.jpg"]
)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$imgs = array_combine($img_thumbs, $img_links);
```

See http://php.net/array_combine

If you absolutely wanted to do that in a loop:

```
foreach ($img_thumbs as $i => $thumb) {
    $imgs[$thumb] = $img_links[$i];
}
```

Comment: array_combine doesn't want to accept string as a key. It is giving me illegal error. I've already tried doing that.

Comment: Very strange...I've tried array_combine before, it kept throwing illegal string error...But either way I tried both of your samples and they work like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to get rid of one of the `foreach` loops and increment the Images array by 1 each time you go through the loop

Comment: could you write an example of what do you mean?

Comment: I am not well versed in PHP, but it looks like @deceze has it written out properly in the second code example.  I was speaking from a logic point of view.